# Where is Qt Maintenance Tool in Homebrew

Tags: macos, qt, homebrew

I have installed Qt with Homebrew. Everything is working fine for Desktop Application Development. But I do not find `Maintenance Tool`. Do I need to install that separately with brew ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not exist, since homebrew tries to be a package manager like they exist on linux environtments. Just like cygwin/msys2 for windows. So they provide one qt build and that's it.

You can still install the official binary distribution from Qt which contains the Maintenance Tool. You can think of the Maintenance Tool as Qt's internal package manager, that can install official Qt binaries.

Comment: @Neel Basu, If you install  from Qt,  the Maintenance Tool, most likely, won't manage your existing Homebrew installation .. why you want the tool while you are using brew?

Comment: I want the Android, IOS development extensions

Comment: Not sure why they'd package QT Designer if they where going to cut out the maintainance tool. Being able to select the required kits is part of the whole process. Damn.

Comment: This answer is wrong. HomeBrew is nothing like MSYS2 and Cygwin. If you want to compare it with anything on Windows it is Chocolatey.

Comment: That comparison may be more accurate, but the answer isn't wrong because of that. Where exactly do you see the differences?